# org.json.JSONException: Value Error of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, php, android, json, android-volley

i am webscrapping a website for education only and trying to show returned JsonResponse but while app runs, it throws an error ***org.json.JSONException: Value Error of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject***. i found several questions similar to this but i didn't got any useful answer and they also contains incomplete inforrmation about problem.
following are codes that might a cause for this error. i hope that this thread will also help others because i am trying to give more information regarding to this problem.

**MainActivity.java**

```
private void apicall() {


        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

        final StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject(response);


                            if (jsonObject1.getString("active").equals("0")) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Your account temporarily disabled by admin", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                preferences.edit().clear().apply();
                                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), login.class);
                                in.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                startActivity(in);
                                finish();
                            }

                            if (!jsonObject1.getString("session").equals(getSharedPreferences(constant.prefs, MODE_PRIVATE).getString("session", null))) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Session expired ! Please login again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                preferences.edit().clear().apply();
                                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), login.class);
                                in.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                startActivity(in);
                                finish();
                            }

                            balance.setText(jsonObject1.getString("wallet"));

                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                                hometext.setText(Html.fromHtml(jsonObject1.getString("homeline"), Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
                            } else {
                                hometext.setText(Html.fromHtml(jsonObject1.getString("homeline")));
                            }




                            ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<>();
                            ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

                            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject1.getJSONArray("result");
                            for (int a = 0; a < jsonArray.length(); a++){
                                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(a);

                                name.add(jsonObject.getString("market"));
                                result.add(jsonObject.getString("result"));

                            }


                            adapter_result rc = new adapter_result(MainActivity.this,name,result);
                            recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, 2));
                            recyclerview.setAdapter(rc);
                            rc.notifyDataSetChanged();


                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                            editor.putString("wallet", jsonObject1.getString("wallet")).apply();
                            editor.putString("homeline", jsonObject1.getString("homeline")).apply();
                            editor.putString("code", jsonObject1.getString("code")).apply();
                            is_gateway = jsonObject1.getString("gateway");


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();


                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        error.printStackTrace();

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Check your internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
        ) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

                params.put("mobile", preferences.getString("mobile", null));
                params.put("session",getSharedPreferences(constant.prefs, MODE_PRIVATE).getString("session", null));

                return params;
            }
        };
        postRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        requestQueue.add(postRequest);
    }
```

**home.php**

```
<?php
include "../connection/config.php";
extract($_REQUEST);

// if(rows(query("select sn from users where mobile='$mobile' and session ='$session'")) == 0){
//     $data['msg'] = "You are not authrized to use this";
      
//     $dd = query("select session,active from users where mobile='$mobile'");
//     $d = fetch($dd);
//     $data['session'] = $d['session'];
//     $data['active'] = $d['active'];
    
//     echo json_encode($data);
//     return;
// }

require_once "../scrap/data/support/web_browser.php";
require_once "../scrap/data/support/tag_filter.php";

$htmloptions = TagFilter::GetHTMLOptions();

$url = "https://dpboss.mobi/";
$web = new WebBrowser();
$result = $web->Process($url);

if (!$result["success"])
{
    echo "Error retrieving URL.  " . $result["error"] . "\n";
    exit();
}

if ($result["response"]["code"] != 200)
{
    echo "Error retrieving URL.  Server returned:  " . $result["response"]["code"] . " " . $result["response"]["meaning"] . "\n";
    exit();
}

$baseurl = $result["url"];

$html = TagFilter::Explode($result["body"], $htmloptions);

$root = $html->Get();
$rows = $root->Find("div.satta-result h4");
$h5rows = $root->Find("div.satta-result h5");


foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    $temp_h4[] = $row->GetInnerHTML();
}
    
foreach ($h5rows as $row)
{
    $temp_h5[] = $row->GetInnerHTML();
}


$get = query("select * from gametime_new");
while($xc = fetch($get))
{
    $time = array_search($xc['market'], $temp_h4);
    $mrk['market'] = $xc['market'];
    $mrk['result'] = $temp_h5[$time];
    $data['result'][] = $mrk;
}

  
$dd = query("select sn,wallet,active,session,code from users where mobile='$mobile'");
$d = fetch($dd);

$nt = query("select homeline from content where sn='1'");
$n = fetch($nt);

if($d['code'] == "0")
{
    $code = $d['sn'].rand(100000,9999999);
    query("update users set code='$code' where mobile='$mobile'");
}
else
{
    $code = $d['code'];
}

if(rows(query("select sn from gateway_config where active='1'")) > 0){
    $data['gateway'] = "1";
} else {
    $data['gateway'] = "0";
}


$data['code'] = $code;
$data['wallet'] = $d['wallet'];
$data['active'] = $d['active'];
$data['session'] = $d['session'];
$data['homeline'] = $n['homeline'];


echo json_encode($data);
```

**JsonResponse**

```
{"result":[{"market":"SRIDEVI","result":"249-54-356"},{"market":"TIME BAZAR","result":"568-98-279"},{"market":"MILAN DAY","result":"133-74-248"},{"market":"RAJDHANI DAY","result":"123-63-148"},{"market":"KALYAN","result":"266-44-130"},{"market":"SRIDEVI NIGHT","result":"588-11-489"},{"market":"NIGHT TIME BAZAR","result":"258-52-129"},{"market":"MILAN NIGHT","result":"568-98-440"},{"market":"KALYAN NIGHT","result":"447-57-188"},{"market":"RAJDHANI NIGHT","result":"458-76-790"},{"market":"MAIN BAZAR","result":"377-76-367"},{"market":"WORLI MUMBAI","result":"124-70-145"},{"market":"PUNA BAZAR","result":"350-89-379"},{"market":"MILAN MORNING","result":"123-63-148"}],"gateway":"1","code":null,"wallet":null,"active":null,"session":null,"homeline":"WELCOME TO BETPLAY"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
 try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject2 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    // do something
    Toast.makeText(context, jsonObject2.getString("active"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Comment: although this is not what i actually want but this answer clears me that in which snippets i have to look at. thanks for your reply